# Jqgrid is not updating with new data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have jqgrid implementation and I am unable to load data in it. I am attaching code, Please let me know. I am successfully retrieving data from the controller and unable reload the jqgrid with new data.

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    alert(j + " " + k);
    var d = { 'firstField': i, 'secondField': j, 'thirdField': k }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/TodoList/searchdata',
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: d,
        success: function(data) {
            callme(data);
        }
    })

});

function callme(newone1) {
    var my = JSON.stringify(newone1.rows);
    alert(my);
    /*
        Json showing in this alert is 
        [{"accntname":"BSNL","BU":"BCS","salesop":50000,"isdormant":true},
         {"accntname":"TATA","BU":"HPSD","salesop":50000,"isdormant":false}]
        */

    $grid.jqGrid('clearGridData');
    $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        datatype: 'local',
        data: my
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Jqgrid which I am trying to reload with new data:

```
var mydata = [];
$grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    colModel: [
        { name: "accntname", align: "center", title: false, width: 400, resizable: false, sortable: false },
        { name: "BU", width: 125 },
        { name: "salesop", align: "center", width: 125, sorttype: "date" },
        { name: "isdormant", align: "center", width: 125, sorttype: "date" }
    ],
    caption: "Viz Test",
    pager: '#pager',
    search: true,
    multiselect: true
});
```

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are receiving is json, which is what Jqgrid expects, there for you should not be stringifying the data. Modify the function to

```
function callme(newone1) {
    $grid.jqGrid('clearGridData');
    $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
      datatype: 'local',
      data: newone1.rows // modify this
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Side note: The `traditional: true` ajax option is not required (your not sending an array to the controller)